# Ошибка при поиске в датафрейме значения из переменно

Tags: python, pandas

Добрый день пытаюсь осуществить поиск в датафрейме pandas значения из переменной

```
 
import datetime

import gspread
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date as dt
from datetime import datetime
import time

# connect got Google Sheets
gc = gspread.service_account(filename="/home/whitehercog/credentials/lookysymbiot-8bd1d380b0c4.json")
# list all available spreadsheets
sh = gc.open_by_key('1e8byu8VovhBsEc9mG5DRxayywP8zaA2DzpsAcAuboLc')

worksheet = sh.sheet1
worklist = worksheet.get_all_values()

# pandas df
Ddf = pd.DataFrame(worksheet.get_values('A2:E30'),
                   columns=['Worked_date', 'Worker', 'Start_smene', 'End_smene', 'Chat_id_worker'])


Ndf = pd.DataFrame(worksheet.get_values('F2:J30'),
                   columns=['Worked_date', 'Worker', 'Start_smene', 'End_smene', 'Chat_id_worker'])

Ndf['Worked_date'] = pd.to_datetime(Ndf.Worked_date, format='%d.%m.%Y')

# date variable
wdate = time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
wtime = time.strftime("%H:%M")

getworker = Ddf.loc(wdate)


print(getworker)
```

при старте получаю данную ошибку

```
KeyError: '15.11.2022'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/whitehercog/PycharmProjects/looky_simbiot_monitoring/google_sheets_connect/google_sheets.py", line 32, in <module>
    getworker = Ddf.loc(wdate)
  File "/home/whitehercog/PycharmProjects/looky_simbiot_monitoring/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 668, in __call__
    axis = self.obj._get_axis_number(axis)
  File "/home/whitehercog/PycharmProjects/looky_simbiot_monitoring/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 556, in _get_axis_number
    raise ValueError(f"No axis named {axis} for object type {cls.__name__}")
ValueError: No axis named 15.11.2022 for object type DataFrame
```

Comment: Индексы в loc передаются в квадратных скобках. Ради интереса, приведите часть данных Ddf.

Comment: Ну и добавлю к предыдущему вопросу: loc - это обращение по индексу (точнее -  по индексу-метке) . А где у вас в датафрейме определен индекс вообще, и индекс, значением которого есть дата - в частности?